# Show that partial sums of this series are bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

Following series:
$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \sin n\phi=\frac{\sin\frac{n+1}{2}x\cdot\sin\frac{n}{2}x}{\sin\frac{x}{2}}$
now i need to show that partial sums of this series are bounded. How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

We know that $$\sin\left(x\right)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$$
 so$$\underset{n=1}{\overset{N}{\sum}}\sin\left(n\phi\right)=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\underset{n=1}{\overset{N}{\sum}}e^{i\phi n}-\underset{n=1}{\overset{N}{\sum}}e^{-i\phi n}\right)=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\frac{1-e^{i\phi\left(N+1\right)}}{1-e^{i\phi}}-\frac{1-e^{-i\phi\left(N+1\right)}}{1-e^{-i\phi}}\right)$$
 and this conclude the proof.

Comment: Hi @MarcoCantarini, how does the R.H.S. show boundedness?  I am struggling to understand this line of reasoning.  To me, it looks like the denominator achieves zero, since the exponentials have modulus = 1 (for phi real), and hence the function blows up at these points.  What do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: Ok, got it - thanks for the nice and simple explanations, @marcocantarini :-)

Comment: @LebronJames You're welcome, I'm glad to help ;)